# Getting error The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts: mobilenumber‎@domainname when send email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtp, nopcommerce

I am using email functionality for email to sms of nopcommerce from plugin.

when i am send email gmail to **"mobilenumber‎@domainname"** then getting error :   **The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts: mobilenumber‎@domainname**

and when i am set `smtpClient.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;` then not getting any error but also not get sms in mobile.

and when direct send email from my gmail account then send email successfully and also sms get successfully.

Please give me some idea how should we handle?

Regards,
Jatin Gadhiya